# How to print term name inside wp post loop

Tags: wp-query, custom-taxonomy, terms, tax-query

I have 3 different taxonomies in a custom post type. I want to print all posts with term name with them.

### for example:

> taxonomy 1 =>taxonomy=banks&post_type=creditcards
>
> taxonomy 2 =>taxonomy=joiningfees&post_type=creditcards
>
> taxonomy 3 =>taxonomy=cardtype&post_type=creditcards

So I want to print all the custom posts with the term names
I am able to print data by entering single taxonomy but how to print data with all the taxonomy terms

### Query

```
$custom_terms = get_terms('banks');

foreach($custom_terms as $custom_term) {
wp_reset_query();
$args = array('post_type' => 'creditcards',
'tax_query' => array(
       array(
             'taxonomy' => 'banks',
             'field' => 'slug',
             'terms' => $custom_term->slug,
            ),
           ),
);

$loop = new WP_Query($args);
if($loop->have_posts()) {

while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();?

<div><?php echo $custom_term->name;?><br><?php echo the_title();?></div>
 <?php endwhile;
       }
       }
?>
```

### End Result that i want in post loop

```
taxonomy1 term,taxonomy2 term,taxonomy3 term
the title

taxonomy1 term,taxonomy2 term,taxonomy3 term
the title

taxonomy1 term,taxonomy2 term,taxonomy3 term
the title
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the terms with the [`get_the_terms`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/) function. You can pass the name of the taxonomy as well as the ID to the function. Make sure to grab the ID correctly inside the loop - get_the_ID() should work. After that it's a matter of joining the results with comma separation. With array_merge you can add also additional arrays that you need.

```
  $x_terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'any-taxonomy-slug');
  $y_terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'another-taxonomy-slug');

  $terms = array_merge($x_terms, $y_terms);

  foreach($terms as $term):
     $term_names[] = $term->name;
  endforeach;

  $names = join( ", ", $term_names );
```